# How to <T extend BaseClass> where BaseClass has a factory function?

Tags: dart, types

Following is a simple class that provides a few helper functions for reading and writing data.

```
class BaseDAO<T> {
  final String _modelName;
  static late final StoreRef<int, Map<String, Object?>> _store;
  BaseDAO(this._modelName) {
    _store = intMapStoreFactory.store(_modelName);
  }
  Future<Database> get _db async => await AppDatabase().database;
  Future<void> create(T object) async {
    await _store.add(await _db, object.toJSON()); //The method 'toJSON' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
  }
}
```

Now the issue with this is that the generic type T doesn't have toJSON function. I tried fixing this by writing an abstract class.

```
abstract class BaseModel {
  Map<String, dynamic> toJSON();
  factory BaseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);
}
```

and extending T with BaseModel. This presents all kinds of issues one of them being that I am unable to write an abstract class.

Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Constructors (including `factory` constructors) and `static` methods are not part of the class interface and can't be inherited, so `.fromJson` won't work.  If you think you need that, then you probably want a callback instead.  As for `toJSON`, you could just use dynamic/duck typing and handle a resulting `NoSuchMethodError`.  Or you could use just call [`jsonEncode(object)`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html) instead, which will automatically try to call a `.toJson` method (note the different capitalization) on `object` if it has one.

Comment: I will go with jsonEncode. thanks

Comment: Now it says the argument type T can't be assigned to the parameter type "String".

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that you want `Map`s but that `jsonEncode` generates the serialized `String`.  You would need to manually try calling `.toJson()` instead then and handle any resulting exception.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `T` object is empty. You need to extend it to some object which provides a method `toMap()`.
Example:

```dart
class BaseDAO<T extends BaseModel> {
  final String _modelName;
  static late final StoreRef<int, Map<String, Object?>> _store;
  BaseDAO(this._modelName) {
    _store = intMapStoreFactory.store(_modelName);
  }
  Future<Database> get _db async => await AppDatabase().database;
  Future<void> create(T object) async {
    await _store.add(await _db, object.toMap()); // <- Dart see that this object extends to BaseModel and has a method `toMap()`,
  }
}

abstract class BaseModel {
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap();
}

class User extends BaseModel {
  User({this.name});

  final String? name;

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {'name': name};
}
```

```dart
Future<void> create() async {
  final user = User(name: 'Superman');
  final base = BaseDAO('ModelName');
  await base.create(user); // <- The user object will be added as `Map`.
}
```